# What's the idea behind md-autocomplete-parent-scope directive?

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, angular-material

I'm learning [angular material](https://material.angularjs.org) library, and there is `md-autocomplete-parent-scope` directive as a part of `md-autocomplete` directive. I didn't find anything in the documentation. Here is the [source code](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/autocomplete/js/autocompleteParentScopeDirective.js). What is it's purpose, what does it do?

Comment: Is there? Not according to the specification https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdAutocomplete

Comment: Sorry, just a moment, I'll correct the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It watches variables on its scope, and then copies them to the parent scope ensuring the data is kept in sync.